# Load Tensorflow 1 Graph in Tensorlfow 2 and use it as Kerras Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, model

I have a **tensorflow :1 graph in a .pb forma**t (a trained model) though I can easly load this frozen graph , however I wish to modify this model and make changes to the architecture and **use it as a kerras model **while using tensorflow 2/kerras API subsequently **train this new architecture**

up until now , I came to know this is a generic type saved model (.pb) and can not be loaded as a kerras object and mainly used for inference purposes

is their a way I can achieve the above mentioned approach ?

- intially tried to directly load the frozen graph using (.pb file): tf.saved_model.load() and tried ways to visualise the model , model.summary() , tf.keras.utils.plot_model() which did not work
- also tried to Wrap frozen graph to ConcreteFunctions and then added the frozen function as a Lambda layer subsequently applied the same method to visualise , but there was an error stating something about model not being initialized before / built etc , also tried to save the resultant modedl in h5 format